# Save plot by pressing on button

Tags: button

I want to save a certain graphics by pressing a button. Thinks work fine for something like this

```
Button["Save",
 export = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10^3]];
 Export["test.pdf", export]
 ]
```

By increasing the number of data points the button press doesn`t generate test.pdf file anymore

```
Button["Save",
 export = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10^7]];
 Export["test.pdf", export]
 ]
```

Simply executing

```
Export["test.pdf", export]
```

after pressing the button, generats the pdf file. What is the cause of this behaviour?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: it might be "timing out" on your system. Try Method->"Queued"

Comment: thanks... it works with Method->"Queued"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10^7]];
Button["Save", Export["test.pdf", export]]
```